# How to disable only some Windows 10 global shortuts to use them in third-party applications?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, sublime-text-3

### 1. Briefly

I want to disable only some Windows 10 default global hotkeys, to use this hotkeys for run Sublime Text commands.

---

---

### 2. Detail

I have Windows 32-bit 10.0.14393. In Windows 10 we have [**many native hotkeys**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445).

#### 1. I want to disable

For example, I want to disable custom hotkeys, <kbd>Win+K</kbd>, <kbd>Win+H</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+Win+P</kbd>.

#### 2. I don't want to disable

But, for example, I don't want to disable <kbd>Win+D</kbd> and <kbd>Win+R</kbd> hotkeys. I often use these hotkeys.

#### 3. Sublime Text keymap part

```json
{
    "keys": ["super+k"],
    "command": "paste"
},
```

---

---

### 3. Did not help

#### 1. [**AutoHotkey Override**](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Override.htm)

My code:

```
#k::return
```

<kbd>Win+K</kbd> global hotkey is disabled for me, but my Sublime Text command `paste` doesn't run too.

#### 2. [**AutoHotkey overwrite global Windows hotkeys to hotkey of application**](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?p=116601)

My code:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class PX_WINDOW_CLASS
$#2::ControlSend, ahk_parent, % SubStr(A_ThisHotkey, 2)
#IfWinActive
```

It is worked for me, but I have bugs, for example:

[image: AutoHotkey bug]

For other hotkeys I have bugs too. It would be nice if someone will improve this code.

#### 3. [**SharpKeys**](http://www.howtogeek.com/194811/how-to-prevent-the-windows-key-alttab-and-sticky-keys-from-ruining-your-gaming/)

SharpKeys program can disable or reassign <kbd>Win</kbd> key, but I don't want this.

#### 4. [**gpedit.msc**](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/31346-how-remove-windows-7-hotkeys.html#post327603)

I can disable [**some default hotkeys**](http://www.askvg.com/tip-how-to-disable-all-win-keyboard-shortcuts-hotkeys-in-windows/), but:

- I can not disable (using gpedit.msc), for example, <kbd>Win+K</kbd>, <kbd>Win+H</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+Win+P</kbd>.
- I can disable <kbd>Win+D</kbd> and <kbd>Win+R</kbd>, but I want to use this hotkeys.

#### 5. [**Simple disable key**](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-disable-any-key-on-keyboard-in-windows-10/)

I download [**Simple disable key**](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/simple_disable_key.html) → I disable <kbd>Win+K</kbd> in program → I restart Windows → <kbd>Win+K</kbd> is not disabled for me.

#### 6. [DisabledHotkeys parameter in Windows Registry](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/winkey-shortcuts-not-working-enable-all-hotkeys/)

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
```

I create string parameter `DisableHotkeys` with value `KHPE`.

[image: DisabledHotkeys]

<kbd>Win+E</kbd>, for example, is disabled for me, but

- <kbd>Win+P</kbd>, <kbd>Win+K</kbd> and <kbd>Win+H</kbd> are not disabled.
- This method is not for disabling, for example, <kbd>Ctrl+Win+P</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+Win+F4</kbd>.

---

---

### 4. Do not offer

- Please, don't offer solutions to disable all global shortcuts with <kbd>Win</kbd> key, not custom;
- Please, don't offer AutoHotkey [**shortcuts redirect to other shortcuts**](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?p=116601#p116601).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Autohotkey for remap any hotkey to send another hotkey using [Send](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) command:

```
#k::
Send {WIN up}
Send {k up}
Send ^+p
return
```

After this pressing Win+K will send a Ctrl+Shift+P which will show Command Palette in Sublime Text, you can use this way to override any hotkey to send another hotkey, set it to something like Ctrl+Shift+F3 and assign that hotkey to Sublime Text's paste(in keybindings) and then use Win+K to send that Ctrl+Shift+F3 to Sublime Text which will call paste.

AutoHotkey script:

```
#k::
Send {WIN up}
Send {K up}
Send !^+{F3}
return
```

Sublime Text keybindings:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+shift+f3"], "command": "paste" }
```

**Edit**:

Seen your `Please, don't offer AutoHotkey shortcuts redirect to other shortcuts.` why not? Above example works even for Win+R:

```
#r::
Send {WIN up}
Send {r up}
Send !^+{F3}
return
```

Text successfully pasted through Win+R in Sublime Text.

**Edit 2**:

If you really like to assign *real* hotkeys you could disable all `Win+{KEY}` hotkeys, and then create *your* hotkeys which will do same as default `Win+{Key}` hotkeys, and for another hotkeys assign your own actions.

For example for Win+R:

```
explorer.exe Shell:::{2559a1f3-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}
```

Works, but for some hotkey its hard to find how to call their actions.

Comment: BladeMight, // **1)** `> Seen your Please, don't offer AutoHotkey shortcuts redirect to other shortcuts. why not?` — Create another shortcut if I also have shortcut meaningless. Why we need additional shortcut `Win+K`, if we have `Ctrl+V`? But I have not thought, I forgot that we can change long uncomfortable hotkeys, which we don't use. `Win+K` is more comfortable then `Ctrl+Win+Alt+Shift+F3`. Thanks for solution!

Comment: // **2)** `you could disable all Win+{KEY} hotkeys,` — it is similar like [**VoidVolker solution**](https://github.com/nnCron/nnCron/issues/5#issuecomment-274026165)? And how I can find digits like `{2559a1f3-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}` for hotkeys? Thanks.

Comment: BladeMight, please, add `return` after each your script. Otherwise, if I use many scripts in one `.ahk` file, all scripts run for me. Thanks.

Comment: @СашаЧерных About Shell::: here is a list of http://g-ek.com/clsid-guid-spisok-shell-v-windows-10 but that mainly for folders.

Comment: @СашаЧерных also here http://ipmnet.ru/~sadilina/Windows/227.html may be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Should explicit shortcut scope, especially who should handle the shortcut.

For general propose - in program A, disable global shortkey handled by program B, enable it to be handled by C (or A itself).

1. Use AHK(autohotkey) - program D, regist this shortkey as global by *physical* in context A.
2. Then use `Send` to **re-send** *simulated* shortcut to *active* window, as if there isn't any *global* shortcut.
   Or use `ControlSend` to **redirect** to *special* window C, as if C handle this shortcut *globally*.

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe notepad.exe
$#q::#q ;this will block #q from windows when in notepad.exe
;or
;  $#q::ControlSend ,,#q,ahk_exe C.exe  ;assume C could hanlde #q globally
#If
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my day, that goddamn Webex was stealing shortcuts from Intellij by replacing them globally, now I could finally fix it with resending the same shortcut to Intellij instead of Webex.

#IfWinActive, ahk_exe idea64.exe
    {
        ^+z::ControlSend ,,^+z, ahk_exe idea64.exe
        ^+d::ControlSend ,,^+d, ahk_exe idea64.exe
    }

Answer (score 2):

I also searched for a way to prevent Windows 10 from opening it's own Clipboard when pressing Win+V because I want to assign Ditto to it.
I finally got it working in Win10 (20H2).

To free Win+V (and probably other hotkeys too)

1. Open regedit
2. Navigate to the key
   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`
3. Right-click and select  `New > Expandable String Value` from the context menu. (this is essential as the *normal* "string value" doesn't work)
4. Name it **DisabledHotkeys**
5. Add the character of the hotkey(s) you want to release. In my case I simply added **V** to the value.
   [see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnJsX.png)

6. Log out (via Startmenu) and back in

Now I could assing Win + V to Ditto without getting an error message.

Comment: How does this differ from the similar answer that was submitted 4 year ago?

Comment: I guess it‘s the „Expandable String Value“ what makes the difference. Else it didn‘t work for me on Win10 (20H2).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `DisabledHotkeys` registry value, applied in this branch:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
```

Setting it's value data to `KHP` would block <kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> and <kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> combinations.

Src: [DisabledHotkeys registry value](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/winkey-shortcuts-not-working-enable-all-hotkeys/)

Comment: w32sh, I [**set DisableHotkeys parameter**](http://i.imgur.com/eYHNuT5.png) → I restart Windows → `Win+P`, `Win+K` and `Win+H` global shortcuts run for me like before( . Thanks.

Comment: Just tested it here. It doesn't seem to work for P H and K. It's able to block WinKey + E though. I'd like to delete my answer.

Comment: w32sh, I tested on other hotkeys now. It's able to block only hotkeys  [**like in gpedit.msc**](http://www.askvg.com/tip-how-to-disable-all-win-keyboard-shortcuts-hotkeys-in-windows/). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hyperenable](https://github.com/midrare/hyperenable). You can edit the config to choose what shortcuts to disable.

*Disclaimer: I'm the author.*